# Is it possible for gcc/clang to setup library locations for different c++ versions?

Tags: c++

I would like to know, if it is possible to install libraries in locations, such that gcc/clang only uses them when the specific c++ language is used.

E.g there are specific c++ versions like: -std=c++98, -std=c++03,-std=c++11, -gnu++98, ...

I'm asking here, because I want to install the library boost 1.56 for old c++03 and for c++11.
Apparanty the object files/library files use a different ABI when either c++11 or c++03 is in use, so I have to install Boost for each language version.

---

Additional Information:

I am using Linux Mint 17 with the compilers gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.5.1.

I've already build the boost library for gcc and one for clang.
Now I would like to try some of the new features the C++11 language provides.

Somewhere, I've read, that it is not safe to compile against a library that was compiled with a different c++-version, if it depends heavily on the standard c++ library.

As boost relies heavily on the c++ standard library, I would need for each c++ version another set of boost libraries.

**What I would like to have:**

It would be convinient, if the compiler uses just the correct boost library, depending on the std compiler option:

- std=c++03 => choose boost_atomic_gcc4.8.2_c++03.so
- std=c++11 => choose boost_atomic_gcc4.8.2_c++11.so
- ...

We have this behaviour at least with the c++ runtime, as gcc chooses the correct runtime depending on the std option.

Comment: On the microsoft compiler you can check _MSC_FULL_VER, and do ifdef pragma lib(). not sure if gcc has a similar macro for it

Comment: I believe it's doable with specfiles for gcc, but it introduces serious maintenance headaches.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you have different projects, where you want to use different versions of boost, and you want do choose which one based on which version of C++ you are using? And is this on Linux or Windows or OS X or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution may be to do this from your build system. This might work if you use GNU Make:

```
ifdef ELEVEN
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
LDFLAGS  += -L/path/to/boost-c++11
else
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++03
LDFLAGS  += -L/path/to/boost-c++03
endif
```